# Android observer is not observing

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, observable

So, Im quite new in Android development and also with working on observables. So what I want to achieve is that on every scan tick of the bluetooth scanner, the `scanResult` gets checked and if its not in the list, the observed list `scanned` gets an update, which checks something if this is valid and makes something.
My Problem is that the observe function just runs through once and then never again

```
2021-03-05 22:18:54.522 32057-32057/? D/devices: Got something []
2021-03-05 22:18:54.522 32057-32057/? D/devices: Start scan
2021-03-05 22:18:55.209 32057-32057/? D/devices: Checking Had128_1_1 in scanned
2021-03-05 22:18:55.212 32057-32057/? D/devices: adding Had128_1_1 in scanned
```

As far as I understood it right how this should work, he should here `_scanned.value?.add(scanResult.device)` update and the observer should recognize that or am I wrong?
Could id be a problem with the lifecycleOwner?
It comes from the MainActivity to the composable with `val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current`
And yes, the function gets called in my composable (as I said, if i press the button, I can see on "Got Something []" that it runs through the first time)

```kotlin
    private val _scanned: MutableLiveData<MutableList<BluetoothDevice>> =
        MutableLiveData(mutableListOf())
    private val scanned: LiveData<MutableList<BluetoothDevice>> get() = _scanned

    private val lockScanCallback: ScanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
            result?.let { scanResult ->
                if (fakeWhitelist.contains(scanResult.device.name)) {
                    Log.d("devices", "Checking ${scanResult.device.name} in scanned")
                    val search =
                        _scanned.value?.find { device -> device.name == scanResult.device.name }
                    if (search == null) {
                        Log.d("devices", "adding ${scanResult.device.name} in scanned")
                        _scanned.value?.add(scanResult.device)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun listenForDevices(viewLiveCycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) {
        scanned.observe(viewLiveCycleOwner, Observer { deviceList ->
            Log.d("devices", "Got something $deviceList")
            locationList.value.forEach { locationScaffold ->
                val boxNames = locationScaffold.parcelBox.map { it.boxName }
                val device = deviceList.last()
                Log.d("devices", "$boxNames")
                if (!boxNames.contains(device.name)) {
                    Log.d("devices", "Getting location for ${device.name}")
                    getLocation(device.name)
                }
            }
        })
        startScan()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake here is that you are never changing the value of the `LiveData`. The value of `LiveData` can be retrieved using `LiveData.getValue()` and can only be set using `LiveData.setValue()` and if you have a look over your implementation, you don't use the set method anywhere.

It is quite a common misconception that changing the state of an object will do something to it's reference, or somehow notify a class holding a reference to it, but this is not the case. If you think about a simplified version of `LiveData` you can break it down into having these core functions:

- Having a current value
- Holding a list of potential observers
- Notifying said observers when the value is changed

The only way for it to be able to notify the observers is to expose a method/function that not only sets the value, but also notifies all the observers of the change if necessary.

---

So in your implementation, you retrieved the current value and changed its state, but never actually set a new value to the `LiveData`.

So instead of

```
liveData.value?.add(newItem)
```

We would need to do something like

```
val list = liveData.value
list?.add(newItem)
_mutableLiveData.value = list
```